# Samba file server won't let me login as root only as active-directory user

Tags: 16.04, permissions, samba, active-directory

I made a 16.04 server installed with samba, winbind and some others using parts of this [walk-through](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto). It worked until I played with permissions (for some reason some folders were not accessible), now I find myself locked out of the server.

I can access the share on windows with my active directory username/passwd but I'm stuck outside the server and can only logon with the same active directory user/passwd.

If I try to get to root user it says the access is denied or authentication failed.

```
> me@ubuntu-fileserver:~$ sudo su  
> sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu-fileserver: Connection timed out  
> [sudo] password for me:  me is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported. 
> me@ubuntu-fileserver:~$ su root  
> Password:   Access is denied  
> su: Authentication failure
```

Is there a way to get root access back without reinstalling ?

**EDIT**: From liveCD or Recovery mode I only have a minute or so before this happens:

[Everything stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOlDu.jpg)

**EDIT2**: After making corrections to hosts/hostname (one was different), still cannot login as sudoer :

> host localhost
>
> ```
> localhost has address 127.0.0.1
> Host localhost not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
> Host localhost not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
> ```
>
> host ubuntu-fileserver
>
> ```
> ubuntu-fileserver.domain.lo has address 192.168.0.57
> ```
>
> cat /etc/hostname
>
> ```
> ubuntu-fileserver
> ```
>
> cat /etc/hosts
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1 localhost   localhost.localdomain
> 127.0.1.1 ubuntu-fileserver
> 192.168.0.57  ubuntu-fileserver.domain.lo ubuntu-fileserver
> 192.168.0.3   dc1.domain.lo   dc1
> 192.168.0.5   dc2.domain.lo   dc2
> # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
> ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
> ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
> ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
> ```

I can ping all these addresses by ip or hostname no problem.

Comment: Hard to say. if you have physical access to the server you coud boot it from an live usb and fix the permissions or add you aduser to sudoers.
else you could try this command: pkexec visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/ it will promt login for an user with sudo access....

Comment: First one says the user does not exist, second one says the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resolve the host resolution

**You're having problems with your host server resolution**.  This is configurable in your `/etc/hosts`.

**You can fix this by:**

Reboot your computer.  At the grub prompt select `Advance Options for Ubuntu` and press `ENTER`.  Go into `Recovery Mode`.  (You may have to hit **`esc`** to disable the ping screen.) Continue with:

1. Drop to root shell prompt
2. `ENTER` for maintenance.
3. Remount the root system with:

```
# sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Now edit your `/etc/hosts` ensure you have the following resolved to the ip `127.0.0.1`.

```
127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1    ubuntu-fileserver
```

### Resolve the `sudo` permission

While in the recover mode of the first section run this:

```
$ nano /etc/group
```

Look for the `sudo` group:

**Change from:**

```
sudo:x:27:apollo
```

**Change to:**

```
sudo:x:27:apollo,yourID
```

Add your using name to the contents of the file.  The userID's needs to be separated by a `comma` to have more than one userID included.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost but fileserver is at the static ip I reconfigured it to.  Should I change it to 127.0.1.1 ?

Comment: You may have other items in your `/etc/hosts` file, but at least the two in the answer should be included.  The first line is important because many programs try to location `localhost` for their proper operations.  In this case, your error message shows `sudo` is having a problem resolving `ubuntu-fileserver`.  It's apparent that, that is the change you made that interfered with your access.  You can verify the resolution by running: **`host localhost`** and **`host ubuntu-fileserver`**.   Can you add the results of those two commands along with **`cat /etc/hostname`** to your question?

Comment: You are right! My host and hostname are not the same. I did not notice the difference before, but now I do not know how to edit it. On recovery mode the files are read only.

Comment: You have to remount the filesystem with the command provided in **step #3**.

Comment: Made the changes but still no go. Edited question and looking for info on the Host localhost not found error.

Comment: The problem is with the `ubuntu-fileserver` resolution.  If you can't show the actual IP that it's resolving to, will you edit your message to show the exact output using an example IP.  Also will you pots the output of `cat /etc/hosts`.  Fixing those to items will resolve this issu.

Comment: edited question, adding that I can ping everyone with ip or hostname and they can ping me.

Comment: Your `/etc/hosts` file is missing the second of the two lines that are needed for your localhost computer.  You can leave the other lines you have, but the two lines in the answer are imperative to be included.

Comment: made the correction (& edited question) and checked everything again, still nothing.

Comment: You have two error messages.  I added a section to address the second error message.  The steps provided should resolve both your errors.  After completing the second section, will you post an output of any current errors you're still getting?

Comment: It seems to work out! I can now use my AD user as sudoer! Thanks! 
With that I was able to correct the original question by changing my PAM configuration and I can now login as both AD user and Local user.